# Can a Project be included (or excluded) based on Build configuration (i.e. DEBUG vs RELEASE)?

Tags: visual-studio

Can a project be included/excluded based on configuration - `DEBUG` or `RELEASE`?

I am developing a project and using a `Console` application as a test-bed. The console app gets the privilege of internal access. In the project under development, I have:

```cs
#if DEBUG
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("ClientPeer.TestConsole")]
#endif
```

I know I have the option to manually unload the project when I set to `RELEASE`. Obviously, when I set the solution to `RELEASE` and attempt to compile, *`ClientPeer.TestConsole`* will complain - reminding me that I need to unload the project. But I'm forgetful and I want to automate it through the selection of the build configuration.

*If there is something to make this question more helpful, leave a comment. I'll see what I can do.*

Comment: It's not exactly an answer to your question, but Solution Filters may be of use here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/load-only-the-projects-you-need-with-solution-filters/

Comment: Sounds [XY](https://xyproblem.info/). What's your real goal?

Comment: @Kit: to conditionally exclude/include a project in a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in having the `InternalsVisibleTo` in the release build as well, as it doesn't cause any harm. If somebody really wants to see or use your internal members, he can use reflection for that anyway.

Allowing your testbed to run against the release build is a good thing, by the way. It may allow you to find problems that only exist in the release build. It's rare in C#, but may still happen, particularly if there are other `#if DEBUG` distinctions in the code. For this reason, we generally run our unit tests in release mode in CI, as the developers typically only run them in debug mode.

**Attempt 2**
Thinking about it, you don't necessarily want to exclude the project from the solution, you want to avoid building it in release mode (because that will obviously fail). You may do so by going to the configuration manager, and disable the build for the test project in release.

[image: Configuration Manager]

Comment: Not an answer (per se) but still thoughtful - an *anti-answer*. Even though I may consider leaving the assembly decorated in `RELEASE` (removing the preprocessor), I think it may still be a valid question. Is there a way to conditionally include a project in a solution?

Comment: @IAbstract Still not the exact solution you seem to look for, but this gets pretty close. See updated answer.

Comment: Preventing the project from building is sufficient. Thanks!